# How to cope with hbox overfull caused by hyphenation problems?

Tags: hyphenation

I'm writing my thesis using a custom font instead of the default CMU Sans-serif. I happen to find that, with this font, my lines tend to be more likely to suffer hyphenation problems (or maybe it's just my imagination). Since I use technical terminology constantly (including acronyms, compound words, and in-line math mode), I regularly get the `\hbox` overfull error.

Here an example:

[image]

However, I feel that my lines really aren't that hard to hyphenate. I wonder whether there's something I can tweak to tell my compiler to try "a bit harder" to break lines properly and avoid the overfull error. In some cases I can manually suggest word hyphenation (especially in compound words), but there are other occasions, like the one of the example, where I simply don't know how to solve this issue without altering word choosing (i.e. I don't want to replace "promised" nor change the words in front of it).

Comment: TeX doesn't hyphenate “promised” when the language is American English; but it can do `prom-ised` in British English. You can add `\hyphenation{prom-ised}` in your document preamble.

Comment: Certainly, I forgot to `\usepackage[british]{babel}`. This, however, doesn't solve the problem altogether (it still happens in other places).

Comment: "try harder" and look better: `\usepackage{microtype}`  try harder and almost always succeeed, even if it looks worse: `\sloppy`